# Looking for a One-Button device that makes a call

Tags: speakers, mobile-phone, microphones

In my company we have a fleet of cars, and we would like to equip them with a simple device that when the driver presses a button, it will communicate him with our company's call center.

In a nutshell, we need a one-button speaker that makes calls to a single number so our customers can call us from inside the vehicle.

Comment: You could get a cheep android phone, set up two user accounts, and in the master account set it up to allow only calls to one number, and put a big call button on the screen. Then you customers have access to the other account only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but buying an Android phone for each car in the entire fleet seems like a bad solution.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you need?

Comment: I have expanded my comment, with more options, into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

- You can got a cheep android for £55. This can be configured to have a singe button to call you. Use multi users, so admin user configures the phone, and other user can not re-configure.
- Non-smart are cheaper, some of these will allow you to set a list of numbers that can be called.
- Alternatively if you are in a close geographical area, then consider CB. This is a press to talk half-duplex radio system. Half-duplex means you can not listen and speak (or press button) at same-time. Therefore it does require training: If the remote operator keeps the button pressed, while waiting for a response from you, then they can not hear your pleas to release the button. You will also have to check current regulations, and range.

Whatever you do, test it on one device, before buying in bulk.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how would you configure an android phone to only show this particular app (one-button calling app) and restrict anything else from showing up?

Comment: No I would have to start by finding out. I would look at the multi user stuff, and have your customer only have access to the less privileged user (that is all I know).